# New Notebook Not Loading on fresh datalab create ${MY_VM}

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I attempted the upgrade to the Datalab 1.2.20170525 version today.  I used the following:

```
datalab delete ${MY_OLD_VM}
datalab create ${MY_NEW_VM}
```

After the instance comes up.  I SSH into 8081 and get the GUI dir listing.  Whether I click "Notebook" to create a new one, or try to open an existing notebook (HelloWorld.ipynb for example).  I get the following error:

> Connection failed
>   A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration.

I am dead in the water again with Datalab.  That's twice this week.  I've lost a full day on this stuff.

Ideas anyone?

Comment: This corrected my error.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to have been an issue with the 1.2.20170525 release, in the way that it interacts with Cloud Shell.  It was therefore only visible when running Datalab from Cloud Shell.  We have rolled back the release to the 20170421 version.  If you are still using the affected version from Cloud Shell, please do a 'datalab delete' and 'datalab create' to go back to that version.

I apologize for the pain.  We'll be looking at additional safeguards we need to put in place in the release process to prevent this in the future.  This will be tracked by https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/1388